# a new field with a formula within a report group

Tags: crystal-reports

i am new to crystal report 9.  I have a report that has this outcome.

Let's assume a report with the following fields. There are only two districts.

```
country   city  district  d1  d2  recr-fac
1           1      1              'bigparks'
1           1      1              'cinemas'
1           1      1              'restaurants'
1           1      1              'museums'
1           1      2              'smallparks'
1           1      2              'cinemas'
1           1      2              'restaurants'
1           1      2              'museums'
```

etc.

the report is formatted like:

```
group by district
group by city
```

then the data.

I need a formula in front of the "group by city" so the outcome on the report looks like this:

```
district 1
city 1          "this district has bigparks"

district 2
city 1          "this district has no bigparks"
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have already group by `district` and `City` now create a formula as below and place in rightmost part of the city group.

```
Local StringVar display;

if recr-fac= "bigparks"
then 
display:="this district has " + recr-fac
else
display:="this district has no " + recr-fac
```

Comment: -1: And what if "bigparks" is not the first/last record in the group? You have the potential to display "this district has no bigparks" when the city, does in fact, have big parks if you're displaying this in the Group Header or Group Footer.

Comment: @Ryan Then it will go to else part.. and display what is required.. and this is the solution as per the question... if you think this doesn't satisfy the requirement..why don't you answer the question instead of commenting others